# Data for "Driving is Why You're Fat" graph

Tags: data-request, medical, us-census

I'm reviewing this [Driving is Why You're Fat](http://s3.amazonaws.com/awesome.good.is/infographics/images/000/000/141/original/1360016729?1360016326) graph and would like to find the data behind it, preferably the actual data and not just the ranks. The data sources are vaguely cited in the lower right corner.  Another image  source, but no more information at [hyperakt](http://hyperakt.com/work-detail/236).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's try to follow the sources one by one:

- [Trust for America's Health](http://healthyamericans.org/states/) has obesity ranks (sense probably inverted compared to the graphic) and the proportion (%) of obese people per state, directly linked from their homepage.
- [U.S. Census](http://www.census.gov/) [American Community Survey](http://catalog.data.gov/dataset/american-community-survey) should have this data. They have per-state transport mode usage statistics.
- [Streetsblog](http://streetsblog.net/) is both a blog about (public) transportation and a network of grass root organisations promoting alternate (as in not passenger car) transport modes. I could not find any prominent study, statistic, survey or data source on their pages.

Sorry for the poor return, but I tried!

Answer (score 5):

This [streetsblog blog post](http://dc.streetsblog.org/2010/07/08/car-dependent-states-hit-hardest-by-obesity-epidemic/) has more details and the data [[XLS]](http://dc.streetsblog.org/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/StateDataEdited.xls).